# rename file extension from terminal doesn't work as expected

Tags: terminal, command, rename

I have a bunch of files named like this:

```
file.jpg?sw=450&sh=450
```

I want to batch rename them removing that awful extension and get this:

```
file.jpg
```

I tried this script:

```
for file in *'.jpg?sw=450&sh=450'; do mv "$file" "${file%}".jpg; done
```

and also this script:

```
for file in *'.jpg?sw=450&sh=450'; do mv "$file" "${file%}'.jpg?sw=450&sh=450'".jpg; done
```

What happens is I get this result:

file.jpg?sw=450&sh=450.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash is one way to do it, although I might consider use of `rename`, which renames based on regular expressions.  Consider:

```
$ rename 's/\.jpg\?.*$/.jpg/' *.jpg\?*
```

This says:

- Given the files that match the glob `*.jpg\?*`
- Replace, in the filenames, occurrences of .jpg that have a question mark following them and all characters after to the end: `/\.jpg\?.*$/`
- With the simple string `.jpg`